# Fortran function arrays

Tags: arrays, function, fortran

I am trying to write a function which has a scalar input but an array output.

My example is:

```
Ts(theta) = reshape((/ dcos(theta)**2.d0, dsin(theta)**2.d0, -dsin(2.d0*theta)/2.d0,  & 
    dsin(theta)**2.d0, dcos(theta)**2.d0, dsin(2.d0*theta)/2.d0, &
    dsin(2.d0*theta), -dsin(2.d0*theta), dcos(2.d0*theta) /), (/3,3/))
```

The `Ts(theta)` is read as a 1 dimensional array but I want an output as a 2 dimensional array.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 4):

Of course

```
function Ts(theta)
  real(rp) :: Ts(3,3)
  real(rp),intent(in) :: theta

  Ts = reshape((/ cos(theta)**2, sin(theta)**2, -sin(2*theta)/2,  &
      sin(theta)**2, cos(theta)**2, sin(2*theta)/2, &
      sin(2*theta), -sin(2*theta), cos(2*theta) /), (/3,3/))
end function
```

where `rp` is the right kind constant for current real precision.

Remark: do not use specific functions as `dsin` and `dcos`, they are remnants of FORTRAN 66 and obsolete since FORTRAN 77.

Your syntax `Ts(theta) =` means you probably tried a `statement function`. They are obsolete also. I am not sure if they can be array-valued, you may try it.

Comment: Statement functions cannot be arrays, you have to use declared functions.

Comment: @KyleKanos I am new to fortran, what's the difference between Statement functions and declared functions?

Comment: I tried the following unsuccessfully:program test2
 implicit none
 real(rp) :: Ts(3,3)
 print*, Ts(acos(0.d0))
end program test2
function Ts(theta)
 implicit none
 real(rp), intent(in) :: theta
 real(rp) :: Ts(3,3)
    Ts = reshape((/ cos(theta)**2.d0, sin(theta)**2.d0, -sin(2.d0*theta)/2.d0,  &
    sin(theta)**2.d0, cos(theta)**2.d0, sin(2.d0*theta)/2.d0, &
    sin(2.d0*theta), -sin(2.d0*theta), cos(2.d0*theta) /), (/3,3/))
END function

Comment: First, you have to place the function into a module or as an internal procedure to the `contains` section of the program. Second, you have to define `rp` if you want to use it. Say, `integer,parameter :: rp = kind(1.d0)`

Comment: @VladimirF Thanks, I got it to work. I struggled with this problem for a long time.